# Model becomes smooth or blurry when I apply a Boolean modifier to it

Tags: boolean-modifier

So I am developing a terrain for a project and the eerrain is a cave system. This so called "terrain" is a mesh. My problem is that when I try to add a boolean modifier, my model becomes smooth. The reason I decided not to use other tools is because of the caves inside the model that make it harder to split and apply fill tool. In this image, I just applied the modifier to split my model into two parts and my model went from looking like this:
[image]

to looking like this:
[image]

For context, this model was originally 16x the size compared to the model I shrunk. Here is a cube for reference:
[image]

If anyone has any solutions please let me know asap since I am still working on this project and it is a fork in the road,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like its got Shade Smooth applied. Select the object, right click and click `Shade Flat`

Comment: Thank you this solved the issue! :)